# How to iterate over WebElements and get a new WebElement in Robot Framework

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, robotframework

I am trying to get `href` attribute from an `html` list using `Robot Framework keywords`. For example suppose the `html` code

```
<ul class="my-list">
<li class="my-listitem"><a href="...">...</li>
...
<li class="my-listitem"><a href="...">...</li>
</ul>
```

I have tried to use the keywords `WebElement`, `WebElements` and `for loop` without success. How can I do it?

This is my `MWE`

```
*** Test Cases ***
@{a tags} =  Create List
@{href attr} = Create List
@{li items} = Get WebElements    class:my-listitem

FOR ${li}  IN  @{li items}
    ${a tag} =  Get WebElement    tag:a
    Append To List    @{a tags}    ${a tag}
END

FOR ${a tag}  IN  @{a tags}
    ${attr} =  Get Element Attribute    css:my-listitem   href
    Append To List    @{href attr}    ${attr}
END
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show what you've tried. Also, define what "without success" means. Is the program crashing? Is it returning the wrong number of items? Is it returning the wrong items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `href` is an attribute of the `a` elements, not the `li`, thus you need to target them. Get a reference for all such elements, and then get their `href` in the loop:

```
${the a-s}=     Get WebElements    xpath=//li[@class='my-listitem']/a    # by targeting the correct element, the list is a reference to all such "a" elements
${all href}=    Create List
FOR    ${el}    IN    @{the a-s}   # loop over each of them
    ${value}=     Get Element Attribute    ${el}    href   # get the individual href
    Append To List    ${all href}  ${value}   # and store it in a result list
END
Log To Console    ${all href}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution (not tested):

```
@{my_list}=    Get WebElements    xpath=//li[@class='my-listitem']
FOR    ${element}    IN    @{my_list}
    ${attr}=    Get Element Attribute    ${element}    href
    Log    ${attr}    html=True
END
```